# OpenVPN on AWS EC2 gives Error Code 1232 (Transmit Failed)

Tags: windows, vpn, amazon-ec2, openvpn

I am using OpenVPN for a VPN client in an Amazon's EC2 machine instance of Windows Server 2008 (32bit).  It  successfully connects,  briefly, and I get

Reply from 10.9.0.1: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=64

Reply from 10.9.0.1: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=64

Reply from 10.9.0.1: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=64

Reply from 10.9.0.1: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=64

PING: transmit failed, error code 1232

PING: transmit failed, error code 1232

PING: transmit failed, error code 1232

It was suggested that I DISABLE/ENABLE the TAP adapter associated with the connection.  But when I do that it causes the instance to freeze - I am dropped and cannot connect until after I reboot the instance.  No seemingly relevant information is left in any event log (System, Application, or OpenVPN's log), or bugcheck file.

Does anybody know a better way to get OpenVPN to work as a client in EC2?  (Specifically, OpenVPN and EC2.)

Thank you.  -John

(Below are some key settings I'm using in client.ovpn:)

dev tun

proto udp

client

nobind

persist-key

persist-tun

Comment: The openvpn client normally provides a detailed log file that could provide some clues for debugging your issue. You might get some more traction if you posted that log file if you are still experiencing this problem

Comment: I have spent many hours on this same problem.  Did you ever find a fix?  Is it not possible to use OpenVPN in Windows on Amazon EC2?

Comment: I too have the exact same problem on amazon ec2. Not quite sure what is causing this. On another instance its running perfectly.